# SignalR: requesting cookie before sending each SignalR message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, signalr

**Situation:** For a web application using SignalR, for sending messages from server(an Azure WebRole) to a browser, I need to access a browser cookie before sending each message to the browser. The cookie would contain some info to process/decode the message before sending it (I can't do this in java script, due to access complexities of decode algo).
The scenario would be to have the access to the cookie as soon as the message is ready in the server --> decode the message --> send the message.

**Question :** Does it make sense to ask the browser to give me the cookie before each message that I want to send to the browser? Or Does it ruins the whole idea of SignalR (being a always connected tcp)?
If it does make sense, then how would I go about this? How can I access cookie in the Hub?

If this would not be possible then I'd have to store the decode information in some persistent storage in the server.

P.S: I'm pretty new to SignalR, so pardon me if the question is too naive.

Comment: Do you expect the cookie to change between messages?

Comment: @halter73 No, the cookie won't change between the messages.

Comment: Yes my client cookie will change between messages. Need refreshed client cookie on the hub side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies seem like a reasonable way to communicating immutable data from the client to the SignalR server. You can read a cookies from inside a Hub as follows:

```
public void MyHubMethod()
{
    Cookie cookie = Context.Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
    // ...
}
```

Just be aware that the request referenced by `Context.Request` will be very long running in the case of WebSockets, so don't expect to pick up any changes that may be made to cookie after you initiate the SignalR connection.

Comment: Is it the case that Signlar doesn't update cookies within the WebSocket it creates when a user initiates a connection with an instance of a Hub class?

Comment: @Zac I wouldn't try updating cookies on the server from inside a SignalR hub. In the case of a WebSocket hub method invocation, the response headers will have already been sent, so the Set-Cookie header cannot be modified.

Comment: Need to send auth cookie from another site with every hub method call. The auth cookie will change because of sliding expiration so how do I access the constantly changing client cookie from within the server hub so I can authenticate each call?