# SignalR client not sending updated cookies when calling hub methods

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Using JS SingleR client v7.0. Server side is ASP.NET Core V5.0.

When inspecting the server side I get the same cookie value from client for every hub method call equal to that of the cookie value received during the initial connection. This is true even though the cookie value on client has been updated and changed in the time between the connection creation and subsequent method calls to the hub.

If I reestablish the connection, the new cookie does get sent but then again it becomes stale as it is never updated on subsequent hub method calls.

From what I understand WebSockets should send the client cookie every time through it's header but seems to keep providing the old cookie. Is there some setting in SignalR that does some caching on the cookie per connection?

Comment: There're no concept of cookie in websocket,and in signalr hub, it would  always keep the HttpContext(you  could get it in hub with the codes Context.GetHttpContext()) that established the connection.

Comment: A similsar case here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510512/signalr-requesting-cookie-before-sending-each-signalr-message

Comment: Similar case but question not answered. I need to get updated cookie from the client between hub method calls. Context.GetHttpContext()) always gives me the cookie in the state it was on hub connect. But that cookie is stale by the time the next hub method call is made. I need new cookie from client.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. The websocket connection is a single request, the connection cannot be updated per invocation because it's not an HTTP request.